# dynamically created button and its own value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get `data-index` of clicked button:

```
var removePair = $("button[name=removePair]"),
    tbody = $('tbody[name=tb-table]'),  

function DrawHtml(list) {
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var o = list[i];
        html += '<tr name="row-' + i + '">';
        html += '   <td>';
        html += '       <button name="removePair" data-index="' + i + '" class="btn btn-primary mx-1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
        html += '   </td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    return html;
}

$(tbody).on("click", removePair, function () {
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(removePair));
});
```

The only way that I know to add event on dynamiclly added button is to attache it to parrent (`tbody`), and fire by dynamiclly created button `removePair`, but I dont know how to get clicked `removePair` for further logic.

`this` return `tbody` instead of `removePair`

thanks!!

Comment: Pass selector to `on()` method instead of elements. Use `removePair = "button[name=removePair]"`

Comment: try `var removePair = "button[name=removePair]", tbody = 'tbody[name=tb-table]';  `

Comment: `$(tbody).on("click", "button[name=removePair]", function () {
    console.log($(this));
});` is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the selector to `.on()` method instead of elements. As the elements are created dynamically hence `$("button[name=removePair]")` doesn't exists.

*Use*

```
removePair = "button[name=removePair]"
```

```js
var removePair = "button[name=removePair]",
  tbody = $('tbody[name=tb-table]');


function DrawHtml(list) {
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < list; i++) {
    html += '<tr name="row-' + i + '">';
    html += '   <td>';
    html += '       <button name="removePair" data-index="' + i + '"  type="button">' + i + '</button>';
    html += '   </td>';
    html += '</tr>';
  }
  return html;
}

//Create HTML
tbody.html(DrawHtml(5));

$(tbody).on("click", removePair, function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  console.log($(removePair).length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody name="tb-table"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than name attribute use class instead

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-primary', function (e) {

        });
```

Comment: why it is important? I've done the opposite until now. when someone will be stylist in the future, I will know that he will not change the logic of creating a table. why not use `name`?